# fitting curve with nonlinear function in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I've a problem using matlab. I need to fit a dataset with a nonlinear function like:

```
f=alfa*(1+beta*(zeta))^(1/3)
```

where `alfa` and `beta` are the coefficients to be found. I want to use the least squares method. How can I do this with the command `lsqcurvefit`? Otherwise, there are other ways to solve my problem?
Thank so much.
Here there is the dataset:

```
zeta    val
0.001141174 1.914017718
0.010606563 1.36090774
0.021610291 1.906194276
0.070026172 1.87606762
0.071438139 1.877264055
0.081679327 1.859341737
0.101181292 2.518896436
0.107877774 2.772125094
0.205038829 3.032759627
0.211802706 1.483644094
0.561521724 2.424261001
0.61500615  2.559041397
0.647249191 2.949944577
0.943396226 2.84068921
1.091107474 3.453699422
1.175260761 2.604008404
1.837813003 4.00262983
2.057613169 4.565849247
2.083333333 3.779001445
3.188521323 4.430824069
4.085801839 7.766971568
4.22832981  5.711800741
4.872107186 4.949950059
9.756097561 10.78574156
```

Comment: An obscenely poor (noisy) set of data. Worse, the noise variance is clearly not at all close to uniform across the series, making the use of least squares problematic. Get better data before you even bother to try such a model.

Comment: If my answer helped you, I would appreciate if you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `fit`-function with `fitType=Power2`

```
fitobject = fit(zeta2,val,'Power2')
```

you can also use the `cftool` to manually determine your coefficients, especially if you want to keep the `(1/3)`. Maybe Least-Squares is not the best solution for your data, as woodchips said.

be aware that you have to substitute your `zeta`:

```
zeta2 = 1+beta*(zeta)
```

you can determine the coefficients as follows:

```
coeffvalues(fitobject)
```